# Date presentation with AngularJS - how costly is a filter?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date, angularjs-filter

I think the angular date and currency filters are really slick, but I've read some commentary online saying that filters negatively impact performance. I'm working on an enterprise app that will be handling all different types of date objects, and we want to render the formatting differently based on user settings.

Based on what I've read, using the filter directly in the DOM is not the best approach, so I'm thinking I'll extract it to a service. The angular documentation leaves so much to be desired, as you know, and there seem to be a lot of different ways to accomplish this.

Ultimately I just want to use angular's built in date filter for presenting a variety of date formats coming from payloads on various pages to format that date. Furthermore, we have independent user settings for both date and time. The options for date formatting are: `MM/dd/yyyy` and `dd/MM/yyyy`. The options for time formatting are: `HH:MM:SS` and `H:MM:SS A`

I am leaning toward using the built in date filter in a service. I think the ideal answer would just need to contain a bit of pseudocode to get me going. Thanks in advance for your time.

Also - please let me know if you need more info or any code. Not sure what to include here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what I was doing wrong with my first attempt. In case anyone else is looking for this topic, here's the code:

```
app.service('DateTimeService', ['$filter', function ($filter) {

    var self = this
    init()
    return self

    function init () {
        self.formatter = $filter('date')
        self.formatDate = formatDate
        self.formatTime = formatTime
    }

    function formatDate (time) {
        return self.formatter(time, settings.dateFormat)
    }

    function formatTime (date) {
        return self.formatter(date, settings.timeFormat)
    }
}])

// in the controller
DateTimeService.formatDate(dateObject)
```